# How to convert a low voltage (1 - 100 mV) AC signal in the range 1 - 10 Hz to DC for measurement using a DC voltmeter

Tags: signal

How to convert an AC signal in the range 1 - 10 Hz so that it can be measured using a calibrated DC voltmeter. In Australia it is not possible to calibrate a multimeter with a 1 - 10 Hz AC range (eg, 3458A) to the ISO 17025 standard. As an alternative, we would like to be able to use a calibrated 34661A voltmeter (or similar) in DC mode for traceable measurement of 1 - 10 Hz AC. Local ISO 17025 calibration of the DC voltmeter is possible. Our application is measurement of a low frequency A/C signal from an accelerometer.

Comment: You want a *sample and hold* or *track and hold* circuit. But you'll have to accept that any errors introduced by this circuit produce inaccuracies in your calibration.

Comment: 34661A can sample at 50kHz, so you should be able to sample and post-process the data.

Comment: VTC - This is more about the use of electronic devices than it is about the design and troubleshooting of them. Thus off topic here.

Comment: HP made a time-interval-measurement frequency-counter, with 100 picosecond resolution using charge-steering and ADC. Find a used version of that. Its 50 year old technology.

Comment: What is your tracable g reference from?  @MichaelKaras  you have no idea. This is about the design of test equipment or process design for Test Engineering.

Comment: Why not simply use a calibrated scope?

Comment: I think this question is great, and useful to the community and not off topic

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 approaches that come to mind.

1) use gravity for a reference using a simple, safe drop test with DC offset correction

2) use a calibrated accelerometer for reference and excite on a shaker table to test for linearity, bandwidth and gain/offset correction

---

### method 1

Free-fall method with DMM that records DC offset and DC Max values

Given a drop height, h1 and a stop height, h2 with respect to to datum at contact t we get g1h1+g2h2=0 from conservation of energy.  Thus for drop g1 =-1.000...g and g2= h1/h2 [g]

Given the slope from 10% to 90% rise time , \$t_R=0.35/f_{-3dB} ~~~\$

thus 1 to 10 Hz = 350  to 35 ms

Depending on the range of acceleration above gravity you can choose h1/h2 = 1 and get -1g then approx +1g on the cushion for a response of  Δg=0 , -1, ~1g then bouncing until = 0

If you want a higher g on the bounce like 10g then choose a rubber material of spring force,  k and surface area, A and mass, m to choose an appropriate material then you get an accurate Step input with a scope or sample and hold after dropping ( optical sensor) to trigger a reading. Using ΔV= Vrest-Vdrop=1.000g or 0.0000g depending if you want absolute or relative g for calibration.

The 2nd method requires a calibrated accelerometer and shaker table and DC step comparator using S&H or stored Max values for + or -g on DMM.

This can be revised with your calibration error correction process.

Perhaps Method 1 is best with DC step response for a simple test and shaker table for DVT on linearity, gain, offset, hysteresis etc.

## Experience

I have done as a Design/test engineer since 1976 and as Test Eng Mgr 10 yrs. later ... just like calibrating ADC for errors in gain offset then further tests for limits, linearity, monotonicity etc. for accelerometers to precise tolerances.

I used it for OCXO sensitivity (1e-11 Hz) to shock, vibe and 100g drop test 10ms as well later for shipping protection of HDD disk drives 1m drop 6 sides, 2 corners. The secret here is the fall/drop ratio of a linear spring = Δg then use random PU high density glued chip foam for low Q < 5.

### method 2

If you do not have a precision voltage offset supply to null DC you can make one. Most good DMM's have store Max peak readings which is useful for this test if sample rate is >30Hz measure for at least 30 cycles

> With more assumptions on your specs and test plan needs (time, accuracy, purpose e.g. design verification test DVT or production verification PVT), I can share more insight.

Comment: Those that understand my answer and can appreciate the experience shared, please show it.

Comment: Those that cannot understand it ask a question to expand. And don’t be a ratchet and not return